# Scrapy shell - 'fetch' is not defined

Tags: python, scrapy

Trying to use Scrapy shell `fetch` command

```
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
inspect_response(response, self)
```

> > > fetch
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       NameError: name 'fetch' is not defined

```
shelp()
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x10b23ecd0>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://inventory.dealersocket.com/admin/inventory/current>
[s]   response   <200 https://inventory.dealersocket.com/admin/inventory/current>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x10b23ec50>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
```

As you can see there is no fetch command.

Question - How to do request from Scrapy shell?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is only available via `scrapy shell` command. It's not available during the crawl because scrapy engine is already busy with crawling the spider so fetch wouldn't fit in.

However it's possible to hack this together by scheduling high priority request to a temp callback:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def parse(self, response):
        from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
        inspect_response(response, self)

    def _fetch_parse(self, response):
        from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
        inspect_response(response, self)

    def fetch(url):
        # schedule high priority requests directly
        crawler.engine.schedule(Request(url, self._fetch_parse, priority=1000))
```

When prompted to shell in `parse` you can:

```
crawler.spider.fetch('http://stackoverflow')
# ctrl+d to exit and wait for fetch to trigger.
```